# How to style the <details> tag when open using Tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css

In css I use this to style another element when the  tag is open.
How is it possible to do the same using Tailwind ?

```
.filesParent[open] .class {
// styles..
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo can add the rule in your tailwind css file.

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#using-a-custom-css-file

```css
/* ./src/tailwind.css */
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
  .filesParent[open] .class {
    // styles..
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In Tailwind v3.3.2, it is possible to use an advanced selector to toggle a deep child from one state to another based on `open`.

Tailwind has a variant for [open/closed](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#open-closed-state). Then [together with arbitrary variants](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#using-arbitrary-variants), we can apply styles only when `open` is activated.

Combining the two features like so `[&_svg]:open:-rotate-180` gives us:

1. select a child svg
2. when the details is open
3. rotate -180 degrees (this could be any class/style you need)

Here's a [tailwind playground example](https://play.tailwindcss.com/UjxLorKs1S) and reproduced below.

```html
<div class="container mx-auto">
  <!-- notice here, the key rule is `[&_svg]:open:-rotate-180` -->
  <details class="border-2 border-dashed border-stone-500 p-4 [&_svg]:open:-rotate-180">
    <!-- notice here, we have disabled the summary's default triangle/arrow -->
    <summary class="flex cursor-pointer list-none items-center gap-4">
      <div>
        <!-- notice here, we added our own triangle/arrow svg -->
        <svg class="rotate-0 transform text-blue-700 transition-all duration-300" fill="none" height="20" width="20" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
          <polyline points="6 9 12 15 18 9"></polyline>
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div>Open this box</div>
    </summary>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce eget varius quam. Nunc et fringilla erat. Suspendisse sagittis tellus et metus mattis iaculis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Pellentesque rhoncus sapien nec mauris lacinia, at mollis tortor hendrerit. Donec a libero erat. Cras sed purus sit amet justo vehicula interdum. Praesent orci erat, volutpat at suscipit sit amet, ultricies vitae dui. Nulla vel libero eros. Donec viverra tellus eu ex finibus ultrices id sit amet quam. Vivamus nibh massa, iaculis vitae odio at, porta eleifend elit. Sed molestie placerat lobortis. Pellentesque non fringilla tellus, eget ultricies arcu. Integer vitae vehicula ante. Donec eleifend neque eget vehicula tristique.</p>
  </details>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with tailwind classes by combining [styling based on parent state](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#styling-based-on-parent-state) with the [open/closed state](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#open-closed-state).

On the `.filesParent` `details` elements you would add the `group` class. Then on the `.class` elements you can add `group-open:<tailwind class>`.

Comment: For those who prefer visual examples, this would be like this: `<details class="group cursor-pointer"><summary class="p-2 font-bold flex items-center group-open:text-primary-red"> summary content</summary>the expanded content</details>`

Comment: This is the only right answer.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the `@apply` rule in my Tailwind.css file

```
.FilesParent[open] .class {
  @apply text-red-violet-500
}
```